# pack figure doesn't work with computeFigure

Tags: rascal

I seem to have a problem with the pack-figure and using computeFigure.

Below is some code to reproduce the behaviour I have.

```
public void main() {
    bool redraw = false;
    str boxWidthProp = "";

    Figure topBar = hcat([text("Width"), combo(["1", "2"], void(str s){ boxWidthProp = s; }, hshrink(0.1))
    , button("Redraw", void() {redraw = true; }, resizable(false))], vshrink(0.05), hgap(5));

    Figure getTreemap() {
    return computeFigure(bool () { bool temp = redraw; redraw = false; return temp; }, Figure() {
                int sz = 20;
                if (boxWidthProp == "2")
                    sz = 100;
                b = box(size(sz, sz), fillColor("Red"), resizable(false));
                t = text(str() {return "w: <sz>; prop: <boxWidthProp>"; });
                Figures boxes = [];
                boxes += b;
                boxes += t;

                //return pack(boxes, std(gap(5)));
                return vcat([t,b]);
            });
    }

    vc = vcat([topBar, getTreemap()]);
    render(vc);
}
```

When running this code, you get a new screen with a combo, button, label and a box.

- When you change the combo you'll see the value of the label change.
- When you click the button the box will change (it's size).
- When you change the combo again, you'll see the label change and clicking - The button will do it's job again.
- This can continue.

Now uncomment the line "return pack ..." and comment "return vcat".
Run the code again.

You will see the same screen.

- Changing the combo works.
- Clicking the button will change the box.
- **But from now on everything stops.**
- Changing the combo, nothing.
- Clicking the button, nothing.

My guess here is that there is a problem with the pack-figure. But I'm a total newbie with rascal (and eclipse), so it might be that I'm missing something.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me as well. I'll post it in the issue tracker.

Comment: https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/issues/929